# Combining similar jQuery statements

Tags: jquery

What would be the best way of combining the below jQuery statements - which all seem to be doing the same thing but are handling different events?

I'm hoping to make my code more efficient by doing this.

```
 $(document).on('change click blur', '.roomFac', function () {
        var park = $("#park2").val();
        var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
        var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
        var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
        var facilities = "";
        $('select[name*=roomFac]').each(function () {
            facilities += $(this).val();
            facilities += ",";
        });
        var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
            'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
            'facilities=' + facilities;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#mon').html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    // search - park2

    $("#park2").on("change click blur", function () {
        var park = $("#park2").val();
        var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
        var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
        var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
        var facilities = "";
        $('select[name^=roomFac]').each(function () {
            facilities += $(this).val();
            facilities += ",";
        });
        facilities = substring(0, facilities.length - 1)
        var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
            'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
            'facilities=' + facilities;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#mon').html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    // search - lecturestyle2

    $("#lecturestyle2").on("change click blur", function () {
        var park = $("#park2").val();
        var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
        var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
        var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
            var facilities = $('#roomFac').val().join( ',' );
        var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
            'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
            'facilities=' + facilities;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#mon').html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    // search - room_structure2

    $("#room_structure2").on("change click blur", function () {
        var park = $("#park2").val();
        var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
        var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
        var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
            var facilities = $('#roomFac').val().join( ',' );
        var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
            'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
            'facilities=' + facilities;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#mon').html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    // search - groupSize2

    $("#slider2").on("change click blur", function () {
        var park = $("#park2").val();
        var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
        var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
        var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
                var facilities = $('#roomFac').val().join( ',' );
        var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
            'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
            'facilities=' + facilities;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#mon').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have the callbacks be named functions and give the varying parts as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and use that as handler:

```
$(document).on('change click blur', '.roomFac', eventFunc);
$("#park2").on("change click blur", eventFunc);
$("#lecturestyle2").on("change click blur", eventFunc);
$("#room_structure2").on("change click blur", eventFunc);
$("#slider2").on("change click blur", eventFunc);

function eventFunc()
{
    var park = $("#park2").val();
    var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
    var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
    var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
    var facilities = "";
    $('select[name*=roomFac]').each(function () {
        facilities += $(this).val();
        facilities += ",";
    });
    var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
        'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
        'facilities=' + facilities;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#mon').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the comma:

```
$('#park2,#lecturestyle2,#roomstructure2,#slider2').add(document).on(/* blah blah blah*/)
```

Since you can't put `$('document')` in the `$('somestring')` form, I'm appending it to the jquery list via [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)